# Pourquoi les toilettes, wc et autres latrines sont-elles au pluriel?

Tags: histoire, noms, pluriel

Les lieux d'aisances ont tendance à être au pluriel en français, du moins en France¹ : *latrines* (de nos jours guère usité au singulier), *toilettes* (qui n'a ce sens qu'au pluriel, encore qu'on trouve parfois le singulier dans « *papier (de) toilette(s)* »), *w.c.*, et jusqu'aux *lieux d'aisances*. Mais pourquoi diantre ce pluriel, auquel je ne trouve aucune justification ni sémantique ni étymologique, et qui semble être une spécificité du français ?

¹  <sub>Il semblerait que le singulier soit plus courant dans d'autres pays francophones, là encore je me demande pourquoi.</sub>

Comment: De mémoire on dit *la toilette* en Belgique francophone.

Comment: Un ami belge m'a donné l'explication suivante: En France les toilettes sont au pluriel parce qu'il faut en visiter plusieurs avant d'en trouver une propre.

Comment: Ce n’est cependant pas le cas partout. Plusieurs de mes amis belges (je suis trop à cheval sur la frontière pour être un bon exemple) utilisent systématiquement le pluriel.

Comment: Los baños, los servicios... pareil en español! En dehors de l'aspect technique, on notera l'usage du pluriel pour tout simplement *ne pas porter l'attention sur l'objet dans la phrase*. Le pluriel rend un peu plus floue la notion et peut être pratique comme figure de style dans le cas oú le sujet en lui-même est délicat (parler des toilettes en publique est tout un art). Attention c'est hautement subjectif et peut-être biaisé par mes impressions personnelles.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

*Le Bon Usage* (édition 2008, 511d) dit :

> Beaucoup de noms désignant les lieux d'aisances s'emploient au pluriel même quand il s'agit d'une seule installation (à cause du fait que, dans les endroits publics, il y a d'ordinaire plusieurs installations)

Il ajoute que l'on peut utiliser le singulier pour insister sur le fait qu'il n'y a qu'une seule installation. Il fait enfin une distinction entre France et Belgique pour *water-closet*, *cabinet*, *toilette*, *lavabo*, pour lesquels le singulier serait habituel en Belgique.

Comment: Je confirme, en Belgique, dire _Je vais à la toilette_ est aussi courant que _Je vais aux toilettes_.

Comment: Idem au Québec où j'ai beaucoup entendu *Je vais à la toilette*.

Answer (score 11):

Pour « les latrines », il est probable que c'est parce que, dans l'antiquité, le lieu était un espace de convivialité, avec plusieurs « postes de travail » (je n'ai pas de meilleure description), ce qui permettait de discuter, chacun utilisant sa latrine.

[image: Latrines à Éphèse]

(trouvé sur http://www.ephesus.us)

Après, est-ce que le pluriel est resté pour les autres mots désignant le lieu pour suivre l'usage « des latrines », voici un mystère sur lequel il nous faudra méditer.

Answer (score 0):

L'emploi du pluriel *les toilettes*, pour désigner par **euphémisme** un cabinet d'aisances, date du XXe siècle.

Answer (score 0):

Je crois que c'est parce qu'à l'origine, ces "commodités", "les lieux" étaient multiples: on proposait plusieurs "postes de travail" comme dit Sylvain Peyronnet.
C'était plus convivial, avant la pudeur individualiste et avant l'accession au luxe des salles de bain et "Water-Closets" individuels, non communautaires.