# What is the exact term for a "toilet", the object itself?

Tags: vocabulaire

I keep seeing *la toilette*, but this also refers to the lavatory itself and I am unsure if it's really the exact term that would be used for the flushable object we  call the toilet. Is *la toilette* the best translation?

Comment: Une question immense. Une réponse rapide, passe-partout mais par trop incomplète, sera de désigner l’appareil par *«**toilette**»*, tout simplement. On dit aussi *«**le bol**»* (voire *«**la bol**»* dans certaines régions du Canada francophone). La salle, elle, est souvent, mais pas toujours non plus, nommée au pluriel: *«les toilettes»*.

Comment: toilettes : ***toujours*** au pluriel, pour ce sens, en français « de France »

Comment: Dans le même registre il y a cette autre question: [Pourquoi les toilettes, wc et autres latrines sont-elles au pluriel?](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/889/364)

Answer (score 2):

En France, dans la terminologie en usage dans les grandes surfaces de bricolage, on parle de **WC** pour désigner le meuble en céramique.

Dans le langage familier on parle de **trône**.

Comment: WC se prononce d'ailleurs ["\ve.se\"](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/W.C.) et non "double \ve.se\", sûrement par contraction.